# unmet dependencies after an upgrade to Debian 8

Tags: debian, apt

After upgrading an `amd64` Debian 7 to 8 I can not upgrade `grep`. What do I have to do to fix this?

```
root@xyz:~# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  grep
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
root@xyz:~# apt-get install grep
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 grep : PreDepends: libpcre3 (>= 1:8.35) but 1:8.30-5 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@xyz:~#
```

Comment: Can you please post the output of 'apt-cache policy' and the content of your sources file(s)?

Answer (score 0):

On https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/libpcre3/download one can download the Debian package which than can be installed manually with

```
dpkg --install libpcre3_8.35-3.3_amd64.deb
```

After that an `apt-get install grep` works.

Comment: While this seems like a working workaround it should have been installed automatically. There is something wrong with your system.